# Can multiple BLEs be daisychained into a single peripheral and simultaneously one or more of them connect to a mobile phone (central)?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, uart, bluetooth-gatt

I am trying to figure out the hardware architecture for a device that has multiple units that need to exchange data in-sync. BLE could be one solution (daisy chain) except that these units need to show up as a single peripheral and connect to a mobile phone (central) where they’d exchange data - perhaps over a UART/GATT implementation. I know that I can have an app on the phone that connects to multiple peripheral but can I have my devices show up as a single peripheral to the phone? And if so, how is this implemented? Is there a resource I can educate myself on?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you want to achieve but if you want to send the same data to multiple devices you can advertise.

Comment: to me, the requirement sounds less like 'one' device and more like 'one' network. Have you ever thought if Bluetooth Mesh could be a solution for your problem?

Comment: I agree, it sounds like you need one device, connected by Bluetooth, that acts as a gateway to the other devices. You could use Bluetooth mesh, signee, Lora wan etc

Comment: From the mobile phone's (user's) perspective, I need to both send and receive data to a device, where device is comprised of 5 units. The observation that of the the units will act as a gateway is spot on. Given this as input, is BLE the best way to go about this, and if so, is BLE mesh the approach?